# SQL get list without duplicates

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, tableau-api

I'm using Tableau to display data from an Amazon Redshift Server which I believe uses PostgreSQL.

I have a table that looks like:

```
ID    | Source | Target
proj1 | proj1  | proj2
proj1 | proj2  | proj1
proj1 | proj3  | proj2
proj2 | proj1  | proj2
proj2 | proj2  | proj1
proj2 | proj3  | proj2
```

I'm currently using listagg to combine the target column to a list for each project but run into each project showing duplicates and itself.

My code is:

```
Select ID,
       listagg(Target) As Tools
From Table
Group by ID
```

How do I remove the duplicates and/or the original ID from the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach which should work on any database would be to do two levels of aggregation, one to remove duplicate targets, and a second to generate a CSV list of targets by ID:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    concat_func(Target) AS Tools    -- replace "concat_func" with whatever
FROM                                -- be appropriate for your database
(
    SELECT ID, Target
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY ID, Target
) t
GROUP BY
    ID;
```

Comment: This worked! I added 'Where ID <> Target' after the inner from to remove itself. Thank you!